# ASP.NET - Membership and roles

Tags: asp.net, membership

How to get user roles from Membership provider?

Suppose I have a username and his/her password and now I need to retrieve his/her assigned Roles.

How can I do that?

Comment: It would've been nice if whoever downvoted this question, at least mentioned why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to call the [`Roles.GetRolesForUser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx) method:

> Gets a list of the roles that a user is in.

This method is overloaded and allows you to pass a username to retrieve all roles for a specific user.